# what is the significance of the "+5" after the braces in this css animation keyframe code?

Tags: css, css-animations

I can't understand how the '+5' in the animation rule affects the animation ?
**CODE IS**

```
@keyframes slidy{
    0%{ left: 0%; }

    10%{ left: 0%;}

    15%{+5       
        left: -100%;
        }
    25%{
        left: -100%;
       }
    35%{
        left: -100%;
       }
    40%{+5
        left: -200%;
        }
```

Comment: please share your Output.

Comment: have you checked after remove it?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't affect the animation, it causes parse errors.

There are no information or examples of this syntax in the [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations/#keyframes).

You can also validate your CSS with the [W3C CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input+with_options) by pasting the code there, and confirm that the syntax will produce a parse error.